# TFS power shell task doesn't pass the correct amount of parameters to the script

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

I am facing a problem where I run a power shell script task as part of the continuous integration process and the script is not receiving the correct amount of parameters.

This is the script that I am running

```
Param
(
  [string]$directory_path,
  [string]$website_name,
  [string]$app_n,
  [string]$takePhysicalPath
)
$ScriptBlockContent =
{
    $dirPath = $args[0]
    $websiteName = $args[1]
    $appName = $args[2]
    $takePhysicalPath = $args[3]
    $physicalPath = $False

    Write-Host "Param: directory_path: " $dirPath
    Write-Host "Param website_name: " $websiteName
    Write-Host "Param app_n: " $appName
    Write-Host "Param takePhysicalPath: " $takePhysicalPath

    Write-Host 'Parameter Count:  ' $args.Count

    if ([bool]::TryParse($takePhysicalPath, [ref]$physicalPath))
    {
        Write-Host 'Parsed: ' $takePhysicalPath ' -> ' $physicalPath  
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host 'Not Parsed'
    }   

    Write-Host $dirPath
    Write-Host $websiteName
    Write-Host $appName
    Write-Host $physicalPath


}
```

if I run the script in a powershell function I am getting the values correctly

```
$directory_path = "C:\SolutionsContent" 
$website_name = "websiteName" 
$app_n = "Styles"
$takePhysicalPath = "true"

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $directory_path, $website_name, $app_n, $takePhysicalPath
```

This is the output

[image]

The problem comes when I try to run it through the TFS
[image]

The arguments that I am passing to the script are the following

```
-directory_path "C:\SolutionsContent" -website_name "websiteName" -app_n "Styles" -takePhysicalPath "true"
```

The variable $takePhysicalPath is never passed, below is the output

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You've to write `-takePhysicalPath` instead of `$takePhysicalPath`. As an alternitave you can use the `Parameter` attribue and make it [positional](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/positional-parameters/).

Comment: I did one too, unfortunately I copied one of my testing approaches, but even that it is not working

Comment: What happens if you change your assignments. You're working with `args` but you also have defined parameters with the `Parameter` block. So what happens if you e.g. change `$dirPath = $args[0]` to `$dirPath = $directory_path`?

Comment: just tested and still getting the same amount of parameters, 3

Answer (score 0):

I tested the script, just add the invoke command at the end of your script, then the arguments passing to the script work as expected.

Make sure you referenced the correct param, in the invoke command you posted above $takePhy**i**sicalPath (note letter "**i**") is inconsistent with the param $takePhysicalPath

The script should be:

```
Param
(
  [string]$directory_path,
  [string]$website_name,
  [string]$app_n,
  [string]$takePhysicalPath
)
$ScriptBlockContent =
{
    $dirPath = $args[0]
    $websiteName = $args[1]
    $appName = $args[2]
    $takePhysicalPath = $args[3]
    $physicalPath = $False

    Write-Host "Param: directory_path: " $dirPath
    Write-Host "Param website_name: " $websiteName
    Write-Host "Param app_n: " $appName
    Write-Host "Param takePhysicalPath: " $takePhysicalPath

    Write-Host 'Parameter Count:  ' $args.Count

    if ([bool]::TryParse($takePhysicalPath, [ref]$physicalPath))
    {
        Write-Host 'Parsed: ' $takePhysicalPath ' -> ' $physicalPath  
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host 'Not Parsed'
    }   

    Write-Host $dirPath
    Write-Host $websiteName
    Write-Host $appName
    Write-Host $physicalPath


}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $directory_path, $website_name, $app_n, $takePhysicalPath
```

[image]

Comment: the "i" was a typo error, I am still getting the same behavior

Comment: @Heinrich I tested again and it works at my side. Just please try to use above script i posted, then passing the arguments through TFS. Make sure the parameters' name you passed are consistent with the declared parameters (no any typo error), otherwise the argument will not be passed to the script.